# How to redirect to another page ONLY if the user prints

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been trying to find a way to redirect to another page if the user physically prints. That is, I want to redirect only if they click on that print button from the tab that opens when printing.

[image]

I do not want this kind of method.

```
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
    window.location='http://newurl.com/';
}
```

Comment: You have absolutely no control over *«the tab that opens when printing»*

Comment: That's true but there are events happening before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/ below:

Combining the Approaches
If you combine the two approaches you can detect print requests in IE 5+, Firefox 6+, Chrome 9+, and Safari 5.1+ (unfortunately Opera doesn’t support either approach).

```
(function() {
var beforePrint = function() {
    console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
};
var afterPrint = function() {
    console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
};

if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

Note that your event handlers might potentially have to deal with the fact that they’re going to be called twice per print request in Chrome.

End of excerpt.

Comment: These handlers will run when the preview window is closed (among other times), regardless of whether the document was actually printed.

Comment: The Chrome based (mediaquery) will run only on actual print, unless Chrome switches to print media for a preview... not tested.

Comment: In Chrome 68.0.3440.75, `window.matchMedia('print')`'s `beforePrint` and `afterPrint` both fire before the preview window even appears, and fire again if a different printer is selected. The `window.onafterprint` handler fires after the preview window is closed, even if it Cancel was clicked.

Comment: So ask the user if he or she actually printed afterwards!